# Commands defining espacement around floats

Tags: spacing, floats

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to define different spaces below float and non float listing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66449/how-to-define-different-spaces-below-float-and-non-float-listing)

What are the commands that define the espacement before and after a
float?

I use the `\captionof` command provided by Koma classes in order to
have captioned tables that stay in particular places.
However, they are very close to each other.
My first idea was to use something like `\vspace{1em}` but I would
rather have them spaced just as tables inside floats.
What are the commands that define the espacement before and after a float.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\begin{document}
Here is a table: 

\begingroup
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc}
  a&b\\
  c&d\\
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{Well, a table.}
\endgroup

This is so close! Don't you think? This is so close! Don't you think? This is so close! Don't you think? This is so close! Don't you think? This is so close! Don't you think? This is so close! Don't you think? This is so close! Don't you think? This is so close! Don't you think? 

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{cc}
    a&b\\
    c&d\\    
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Another table, quite similar.}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Which gives:

[image: Space after float]

The vertical space I am  talking about is marker by the red double arrow.

Comment: I uploaded an image and the correponding code. The fact that the float numbered 2. ends up before the non float numbered 1 is another issue.

Comment: @AlfredM.: I would suggest asking a new question about the figure order/placement problem that you have if you can't find one already on this site.

Comment: I did not find it on the site but I suppose some \clearpage will do the trick.

Comment: Better would be to use the [`afterpage` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/afterpage) and issue `\afterpage{\clearpage}`. However, if the float has already been processed, you will still have the incorrect arrangement. So perhaps even `\afterpage{\begin{figure}...\end{figure}}` (not tested though).