# Text starting at the bottom of paper?

Tags: page-breaking, paragraphs

I start writing my thesis in LaTeX. On one of the paper do have a graph and for some reason it split the text and the text are starting at the bottom of the new page.

I am using the `\documentclass[draft,a4paper,11pt]{memoir}` class.

Are their some why where I can define when it should make pagebreak. It would make sense if the last two line of the page would make a pagebrak and that the text could start right under the graph.

See picture:

[image: http://cl.ly/image/472l3N002M2w]

Comment: Not that it has anything to do with the issue at hand, but I spotted quite a few spelling and grammar mistakes in your screenshot. I recommend finding someone more proficient in English than yourself to proofread your thesis.

Comment: You can try with `\clearpage`, but without an [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) it is hard to play with your problem. Do you use `\raggedbottom`? Where is the grapg referenced? Can you move the graph? Can you add a sentence or delete on? This question could be better answered if we had a MWE to play with ...  Btw: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: If this is a problem throughout your thesis, then it could be related to the length `\textfloatsep`. See [How to define different spaces below float and non float listing?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66450/5764) However, without more information, it's hard to tell.

Comment: I see it is hard to answer with the information i wrote. The problem was something in this package. \usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref} When I remove [colorlinks] it all went back to perfect.